# Split controller into individual system in Drake

Tags: drake

I would like to implement a simulation of multi-drone cooperative handling. I used three drones and three ropes connected by 20 ball joints with cylinders. These three ropes are all connected to one load which is a box. Here is the lqr controller for one drone connected the load:

```
def MakeQuadrotorController(diagram_plant):
    def QuadrotorLQR(diagram_plant):
        swarm_sys = diagram_plant.GetSubsystemByName(NAME_SWARM)

        diagram_context = diagram_plant.CreateDefaultContext()        
        swarm_context = swarm_sys.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context)
        #prop_context = prop_sys.GetMyContextFromRoot(diagram_context)

        state_0 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                   0.0, 0, 0.0,
                   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

        swarm_context.SetContinuousState(state_0)

        # Inputs
        input_dim = NUM_DRONES*PROPS_PER_DRONE 
        drone_name = GROUP_PREFIX + MODEL_PREFIX_DRONE + str(1)
        load_name = GROUP_PREFIX + "load"
        
        first_drone_instance = swarm_sys.GetModelInstanceByName(drone_name)
        #load_instance = swarm_sys.GetModelInstanceByName(load_name)

        single_drone_mass = swarm_sys.CalcTotalMass(swarm_context, [first_drone_instance])
        #load_mass = swarm_sys.CalcTotalMass(swarm_context, [load_instance])
        g = swarm_sys.gravity_field().kDefaultStrength
 
        # print(f'Drone mass: {single_drone_mass}')
        # print(f'Load mass: {load_mass}')

        diagram_plant.get_input_port().FixValue(diagram_context, (single_drone_mass+0.01) * g / 4. * np.array([1, 1, 1, 1]))
        
        Q_diag = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        
        Q_comb = np.diag(Q_diag)

        R_diag = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
        R_comb = np.diag(R_diag)

        return LinearQuadraticRegulator(diagram_plant, diagram_context, Q_comb, R_comb)
 
    lqr_controller = QuadrotorLQR(diagram_plant)
```

Here is the whole system:

```
def MakeMultibodyQuadrotor(sdf_path, meshcat):
    ## Add quadrotor
    builder = DiagramBuilder()

    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=1e-4) #time_step=1e-4) #plant = builder.AddSystem(MultibodyPlant(0.0))
    plant.set_name(NAME_SWARM)

    parser = Parser(plant)
    #model_instance = parser.AddModelFromFile(sdf_path)
    model_instance = parser.AddModels(sdf_path)

    ## Setup variables for co-ordinate changing and propeller connection 
    # Default parameters from quadrotor_plant.cc:
    L = 0.174  # Length for arms (m)
    kF = 1.0  # Force input constant.
    kM = 0.0245  # Moment input constant.

    # Change frame for load
    load_name = GROUP_PREFIX + "load"
    load_instance = plant.GetModelInstanceByName(load_name)
    AddFloatingRpyJoint(plant, plant.GetFrameByName("base_link", load_instance), load_instance, use_ball_rpy=False)

    plant.Finalize()

    ## Add propellers
    prop_info = []
    for i in range(FIRST_DRONE_NUM,NUM_DRONES+1):
        next_drone_name = GROUP_PREFIX + MODEL_PREFIX_DRONE + str(i)
        next_drone_instance = plant.GetModelInstanceByName(next_drone_name)

        body_index = plant.GetBodyByName("base_link", next_drone_instance).index()

        # Note: Rotors 0 and 1 rotate one way and rotors 2 and 3 rotate the other.
        prop_info += [
            # PropellerInfo(body_index, RigidTransform([L, -L, 0]), kF, kM),
            PropellerInfo(body_index, RigidTransform([L, -L, 0.06]), kF, kM), # rotor 0
            PropellerInfo(body_index, RigidTransform([-L, L, 0.06]), kF, kM), # rotor 1
            PropellerInfo(body_index, RigidTransform([L, L, 0.06]), kF, -kM), # rotor 2 cw
            PropellerInfo(body_index, RigidTransform([-L, -L, 0.06]), kF, -kM), # rotor 3 cw
        ]


    propellers = builder.AddNamedSystem("propellers", Propeller(prop_info))

    builder.Connect(propellers.get_output_port(), plant.get_applied_spatial_force_input_port())
    builder.Connect(plant.get_body_poses_output_port(), propellers.get_body_poses_input_port())


    builder.ExportInput(propellers.get_command_input_port(), "u")
    builder.ExportOutput(plant.get_state_output_port(), "q")

    # Add meshcat visualizer
    meshcat.Delete()
    MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)

    ## Build diagram
    diagram = builder.Build()
    diagram.set_name(NAME_DIAGRAM_QUAD)

    return diagram
```

I want to know how to just control this system of one or more drones inside, split controller into individual, with the same time checking the status of each drone and the position of the load (controlling them as a model, setting the Q of the rope and load to 0, the thin rope will report an error that it can't be penetrated and it runs very slowly).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your question is about wiring up the diagram, or about the control design philosophy?

Assuming you are asking about the wiring, then the `MultibodyPlant` has multiple output ports -- you can access the state output for the entire system of quadrotors (as I did in that example), or [access the state output from a single model instance](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a00693ff4108f9634a03e5799c9306428). The input ports are a little more subtle, since you have to add them via the `Propeller` class. But you can use a [`Multiplexer`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_multiplexer.html) to take the outputs of the individual controllers and fuse them into a single input port for the `Propeller` system.

Comment: The whole system is made of n drones and n ropes (spliced by cylinders). I just want to control the n drones with a distributed MPC, without controlling the ropes, and observe the change in position of the loads.